# Pasar pocedimiento de SQL a C#

Tags: c#, sql

Hola Necesito pasar este codigo sql a C#, es un procedimiento que realiza redondeo de la fecha
´

```
Set @Fecha =
  DATEADD(mi,-5,SMALLDATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(@Fecha),MONTH(@Fecha),DAY(@Fecha),
          IIF(ROUND(DATEPART(mi,@Fecha),-1) = 60,DATEPART(hh,@Fecha)+1,
              DATEPART(hh,@Fecha)),
              IIF(ROUND(DATEPART(mi,@Fecha),-1) = 60, 
                  00,
                  ROUND(DATEPART(mi,@Fecha),-1)
               )
          )
   );
```

Comment: Saludos. Te sugiero coloques ejemplo de los recibido y resultado esperado; desde luego lo que has intentado y que obtienes que no corresponde a lo que esperas.

Comment: Que clase de redondeo es ese?, la verdad no lo entiendo que quiere lograr